# Sorting an Alphanumeric value in array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, cordova-2.7.0

I am getting a string an array of objects field from the data base which contains a value like:`dataarray=[{name:'xyz',id:' '},{name:'abc',id:'DOC-TEMP-1'},{name:'efg',id:''},{name:'abc',id:'DOC-TEMP-21'},{name:'abc',id:''},{name:'jklm',id:'DOC-TEMP-2'}];`.

I want to sort this array based on id so i tried to do it using sort method  like this:

```
dataarray.sort(function(a,b){
                var a1 = a['id'].split('-');
                var b1 = b['id'].split('-');
                console.log('value in a1: '+a1);
                console.log('value in b1: '+b1);
                if(a1[2] =='' || a1[2]==null)
                {
                    a1[2] == 0;
                }if(b1[2]=='' || b1[2]==null)
                {
                    b1[2] == 0;
                }
                return a1[2]-b1[2];
            });
```

But it gives me uncorrect result.

what i want is it should first show the null ids then the id sort by number .

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small mistake, you are using '==' instead of '=' to assign values inside your conditionals.